# Android eclipse editor: Unable to edit properties

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm facing a strange and productivity destroying problem since this morning.
Properties with no pre filled attributed can't be edited trough the properties editor. (Margins for example) I need to switch between the view and XML editor every time to made even the smallest change in the world, cause I can only change it from the XML.

I tried everything (Restarting eclipse, every click combos in fields etc...). Really annoying.

The properties editor:

[image]

UPDATE: Sound like a problem related to Mountain Lion, so we have to wait for an ADT plugin update ?

Comment: It's unrelated to Mountain Lion.

Comment: Got the same issue in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation in the new property sheet introduced in ADT 20.

We've improved it in ADT 21, and if you download Preview 4 (released yesterday) you can see the new behavior. Here's the fix: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/42238/

Here's ADT 21 preview: http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview

-- Tor

Answer (score 33):

Same problem with ADT v22.3.0-887826

Fixed after rechange current API verion in top of XML editor (Green robot spinner).
I choosed API 18 instead 19. All is work.

Answer (score 6):

I've just had the same issue with ADT 22.3 in Eclipse on OS X Mavericks.

Doesn't seem to be related to OS version, just change open the view in the layout editor and change the Android version (next to the green Android robot icon in the toolbar) to a lower version and it should re-render the layout for a lower API Level and you should find it works fine.

If it still doesn't work, try an even older version and retry.

Comment: Same here but on Windows, your "solution" worked for me, I just wish it was something a bit more permanent. Definite thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

switch to Android-18(or lower) in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right)

Comment: nice - if you only need 18 and under.  Which is fine for most of my work

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33906&q=properties%20editor&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars but no reponse there yet.

Answer (score 1):

I updated today to mountain lion and I have a  the same problem with the last adt
So I'm reading here

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=properties%20editor&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=33906

...it´s a problem with Mountain lion

Answer (score 1):

I updated all package from Android SDK manager! and it solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of eclipse are your using? Did you try the latest version or perhaps updating adt?

Comment: This is happening for me with the latest of both.

Comment: I don't know if it's related but for me it started happening after I update to mountain lion... probably is just a coincidence. I see on eclipse error log view this every time I click a property to edit: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.invalidateVisibleRegion(Control.java:2177)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFrameSize(Control.java:3792)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setFrameSize(Text.java:1700)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5463)
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native`

Comment: I am also running mountain lion. Could you paste a full stack trace.

Comment: @VitalyBabiy sure you can check the full stack trace [here](http://codr.cc/s/38aa45cb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Delete Android 4.4 (API 19).. and close eclipse and open it again.

and make Android application project (ex: hello) and  click the properties.

Today I solved it that way.

Comment: This is going to achieve the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19950455/498949 in a rather less elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

update android sdk tools on the "sdk manager" (open as administrator) and update "android tools" on "install new software" ( https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)  (v 22.6.2).

worked for me - all the best, you all!

Answer (score 0):

Solve your problem by closing of perpective (in windows tab of eclips)