# Setting (dp) values in properties box in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android eclipse editor: Unable to edit properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579594/android-eclipse-editor-unable-to-edit-properties)

I have changed my computer recently with the last version of Eclipse and ADT plugin and I'm confused.
I have noticed some changed with the ADT plugin and now I can't put specific values in the properties box in Eclipse.

I used to click on a Layout (in graphical View); then I went to the properties box and change one of a Layout properties to a specific value like 50dp.

Now I don't have a choice, I can only select fill_parent, wrap_content, match_parent ...
I order to do what I want, I need to edit xml manually.

Do I miss something or not ?

Comment: So I think there is no way to do this like "old school". I noticed some other change like when you put a value in margin properties and press enter, the properties box disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the toolbar just above your layout, use the button with a dashed square in it.

[image: enter specific margin value]

Comment: useful, but works only for margins. Padding, colors and other elements cannot be directly edited from the properties any more. Hope it's a bug they will fix soon: forcing using a measure everywhere feels crazy to me.

Comment: We can already edit the margin by setting specific value. But nothing for height and width. Like FrancescoR said, I really hope they will fix it.