# Can't modify properties with recent update on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, properties, panel

noob here. I'm taking a Java class and we've been creating android apps. I recently updated my Eclipse that already had the plug-in and I can no longer modify the properties in this panel. 
[image]

There are only a few options I can edit from this window. I can always edit the values manually, but I don't have the greatest knowledge of doing so. He sort of expect us to use the properties panel.

I'v googled this problem for a few hours now. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered at the below link: [Android eclipse editor: Unable to edit properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579594/android-eclipse-editor-unable-to-edit-properties)

The problem is with 4.4 (19), switch back to 4.3(18) and that should help resolve the issue for time-being